# google maps api direction with waypoints error

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying draw map to use google api direction with waypoints but when I running to code I get a error which I shared below and my code is below. My google api url is working when I try it in browser `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.005268,28.963338&waypoints=optimize:true|41.011011,28.97067|&destination=41.008955,28.968041&sensor=false`

```
Activity trackbin.spintek.com.trackbin_spintek.MapsActivitym has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4126d0a8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-563,96} that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity trackbin.spintek.com.trackbin_spintek.MapsActivitym has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4126d0a8 V.E..... R......D 0,0-563,96} that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:218)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
at trackbin.spintek.com.trackbin_spintek.MapsActivitym$connectAsyncTask.onPreExecute(MapsActivitym.java:129)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
at trackbin.spintek.com.trackbin_spintek.MapsActivitym.onMapReady(MapsActivitym.java:237)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzo$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
at xk.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
at maps.af.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is

```
public class MapsActivitym extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final LatLng LOWER_MANHATTAN = new LatLng(41.005268,28.963338);
    private static final LatLng BROOKLYN_BRIDGE = new LatLng(41.011011,28.970670);
    private static final LatLng WALL_STREET = new LatLng(41.008955,28.968041);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_activitym);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {
        String origin = "origin=" + LOWER_MANHATTAN.latitude + "," + LOWER_MANHATTAN.longitude;
        String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|" + BROOKLYN_BRIDGE.latitude + "," + BROOKLYN_BRIDGE.longitude + "|";
        String destination = "destination=" + WALL_STREET.latitude + "," + WALL_STREET.longitude;

        String sensor = "sensor=false";
        String params = origin + "&" + waypoints + "&"  + destination + "&" + sensor;
        String output = "json";
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + params;
        return url;
    }

    public class JSONParser {

        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = "";
        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {
        }
        public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                json = sb.toString();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            return json;

        }
    }


    private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String url;
        connectAsyncTask(String urlPass){
            url = urlPass;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivitym.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.hide();
            if(result!=null){
                drawPath(result);
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawPath(String  result) {

        try {
            //Tranform the string into a json object
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(encodedString);
            Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .addAll(list)
                    .width(12)
                    .color(Color.parseColor("#05b1fb"))//Google maps blue color
                    .geodesic(true)
            );

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng( (((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5) ));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        String get_url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl();
        new connectAsyncTask(get_url).execute();

    }
}
```